# Consider the matrix $H_n = (\frac{1}{i + j - 1})_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$. Determine $H_2^{-1}$ and then show the given $H_3^{-1}$ is inverse of $H_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, inverse

Could you give me your feedback ?

---

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We consider the matrix

$$H_n = (\frac{1}{i + j - 1})_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$$

It is interesting to observe that all entries of $H_n^{-1}$ are integers.

Determine $H_2^{-1}$ and then show $$H_3^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    9 & -36 & 30   \\
    -36 & 192 & -180 \\
    30 & -180 & 180 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

---

We get

$$H_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1/2    \\
    1/2 & 1/3  \\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

To get the inverse , we want to execute row operations on $H_2$ until we get the identity matrix. At the same time, we apply those row operations on an $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, and the resulting matrix is $H_2^{-1}$.

We first add -1/2 the first row to the second row, mulltiply the second row by 12, and add -1/2 the second row to the first row. If we apply that to $H_2$ we get the identity matrix. If we apply that to the identity matrix, we get $$H_2^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & -6    \\
    -6 & 12  \\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

To show the given $H_3^{-1}$ is in fact the inverse, we multiply $H_3$ by it and check if we get the identity matrix.

$$H_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
    1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 \\
    1/3 & 1/4 & 1/5 \\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

If we multiply $H_3$ and $H_3^{-1}$ we in fact get the identity matrix

---

Your feedback would be greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: These matrices are known as [Hilbert matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), by the way

Comment: Your approach is correct

Comment: to show something by hand, write out the multiplication of $(60 H_3)   H_3^{-1} $   of two integer matrices.